# Resampling Time Series Data (Pandas Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, resampling

Trying to convert data at daily frequency to weekly frequency.

In:

```
weeklyaaapl = pd.DataFrame()
weeklyaapl['Open'] = aapl.Open.resample('W').iloc[0]

#here I am trying to take the first value of the aapl.Open,
#that falls within the week.
```

Out:

```
ValueError: .resample() is now a deferred operation
use .resample(...).mean() instead of .resample(...)
```

I want the true open (the first open that prints for the week) (the open of the first day in that week).
It instead wants me to take the mean of the daily open values for a given week using .mean(), which is not the information I need.

Can't seem to interpret the error, documentation isn't helping either.

Comment: What about the docs aren't helping? Which docs are you reading? What's unclear about http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#basics ?

Comment: I just couldn't find any mention of the .first() method that I needed. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html using this as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need.

```
aapl.resample('W').first()
```

Output:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close     Volume
Date                                             
2010-01-10  30.49  30.64  30.34  30.57  123432050
2010-01-17  30.40  30.43  29.78  30.02  115557365
2010-01-24  29.76  30.74  29.61  30.72  182501620
2010-01-31  28.93  29.24  28.60  29.01  266424802
2010-02-07  27.48  28.00  27.33  27.82  187468421
```

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Thank you!

Comment: @anon. It is a big library.  You are welcome.  Happy coding.